# Orden no encontrada YUM-DNF

Tags: linux, fedora

Soy nuevo en linux, estoy usando fedora silverblue 32,encuentro que cuando quiero usar dnf o yum para instalar algo estos no me funcionan.. googlando todas las soluciones es instalando el uno al otro por ejemplo yum install dnf .. o dnf install yum .. pero por lo mismo que les comento no puedo instalar nadam, que tengo que hacer para poder usar mi sistema con normalidad?

Comment: You need to be `root` or use `sudo` to install packages with `dnf`.  There is also, `software`, a `gnome` app, that you can use to install packages.  Are you using `gnome`?

Comment: tenia que usar rpm-ostree porq uso fedora silverblue ,

Comment: Ahhh, maybe update your question and answer it so others will learn later?

Answer (score 0):

En fedora silverblue no se usa ni dnf ni yum, el gestor de paquetes que hay que usar es `rpm-ostree`